# Can we get the e-mail address of the logged-in user with a client script?

Tags: discussion, support, users, email

I need to find the e-mail address of the currently logged-in user on Stack Overflow using a client script.

Is the e-mail address stored in cookies or `localStorage`? I don't see it.

What is the best solution for this?

Comment: why do you want the email address? Do the users know you are reading it?

Comment: You can find out your email address at your account page, in the table row labeled "Email". Take a look at your **own** profile: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/205508/ (it will only be visible if you're logged in).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is the email address stored in cookies or localStorage?

Of course it isn't - that would be a breach of privacy. The email addresses of our users are **only** used when moderators or Stack Exchange staff need to contact the person. That is the only use we have for them.

---

We **do not** offer access to our users email addresses. If they wish to disclose them in their about section on their profile, that is their right, but we will not publicly provide it.

Comment: The question is about the _currently logged in_ user. Can you elaborate on the "breach of privacy" part?

Comment: @JanDvorak - The key here is "User Script". OP is asking for his script, hosted on his machine, to gain access to the email address of whatever user is using his user script, while logged into Stack Overflow (or other Stack Exchange site). In essence, us giving him access to the email address of any user that cares to install his user script.